# Ubuntu Server 14.04: Display stdout from startup scripts after login

Tags: command-line, server

I have an application that binds a socket and streams data over a TCP connection.  The script works and runs on startup (called from rc.local), but how do I get the output of the script to display in the CLI?  Echo does not work because there is nothing to echo to yet during startup, correct?  Is there a "buffer" that could dump the stdout of startup processes after login?  When I deployed this on ubuntu desktop, I opened a new terminal window and all program output would go to it.  I am trying to mimic this behavior on CLI so that if I ssh in, I  can see the status of the stream. i.e. "Client Connected", "Bind Success"

Thanks!

Comment: Why not let your script log to a file and read the log?

Comment: Add rc.local to the title.

Answer (score 0):

One way to do it would be to run a script at startup to execute your program in a screen session. That way all you have to do is attach to the screen after login to view the status.